# PFObject can't be converted

Tags: ios, string, swift, parse-platform, pfobject

Then i try to convert a key from PFObject to a String it gives me a error. I can't find anything on Parses website. Please help

```
var findProgram = PFQuery(className: "Programs")

findProgram.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(data["program"] as! String!, block: { (object: PFObject?, error) -> Void in
      if error == nil {

          var objects = object["name"] as! String

          print(objects)

          self.programUpdated.append(object?.createdAt as NSDate!)

          }

})
```

Comment: At which line you have problem?

Comment: var objects = object["name"] as! String

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're going to have to do, try this:

```
//explicitly giving the objects var a type of String
var objects:String = object["name"] as! String
```

You shouldn't get an error after that.

Good luck!

Comment: Are you sure there is an value for the key *name* in your *object* dictionary? What is the error? @BenjaminEibye

Comment: I got what i wanted by object?.objectForKey("name"). Thanks for the help

Comment: Great! Glad I could help. Good luck on your app! @BenjaminEibye

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be the batter way to do that:

```
if let objects = object?.objectForKey("name") as? String{

    print(objects)
    self.programUpdated.append(objects?.createdAt as NSDate!)
}
```